# Core Data saving a NS(Mutable)Array fails

Tags: core-data, nsarray, nsmanagedobject

I'm having a problem with Core Data. I have two Entities (Article and Manufacturer) (one containing a transformable attribute which is an array of the other entity). Everything's working fine till I try to add the array to the NSManagedObject. Here's some code:

```
@implementation HASArticleInitializer

- (void)initialize:(NSArray *)initArray {
    //Alloc and init some local variables
    NSMutableArray *articleEntitiesArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= pageCount; pageIndex++) {

        //Parsing the website

        //For-loop for every object on every page
        for (NSInteger object = 0; object < [articleNumbersOnOnePageArray count]; object++) {
            //Doing other string manipulation and parsing stuff


            NSManagedObject *newArticleEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Article"inManagedObjectContext:context];

            [newArticleEntry setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@", manufacturerNumber, articleNumber] forKey:@"number"];
            [newArticleEntry setValue:articleTextComplete forKey:@"text"];
            [newArticleEntry setValue:articleStatus forKey:@"status"];
            [newArticleEntry setValue:manufacturerName forKey:@"manufacturerName"];
            [newArticleEntry setValue:manufacturerNumber forKey:@"manufacturerID"];

            [articleEntitiesArray addObject:newArticleEntry];
        }
    }

    NSManagedObject *newManufacturerEntry = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Manufacturer" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    //Encoding the NSArray and setting the entity attribute to Binary Data doesn't work neither
    //NSData *arrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:articleEntitiesArray];

    [newManufacturerEntry setValue:manufacturerName forKey:@"name"];
    [newManufacturerEntry setValue:manufacturerNumber forKey:@"manufacturerID"];
    [newManufacturerEntry setValue:manufacturerCount forKey:@"count"];
    [newManufacturerEntry setValue:articleEntitiesArray forKey:@"articles"];
    NSLog(@"%@", articleEntitiesArray);
}


@end
```

I tried everything I thought it could or couldn't help, I've really spend days on this, but I always get the following error when the AppDelegate's `- (IBAction)saveAction:(id)sender` method is called:

```
[15836:a057] -[NSManagedObject encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001896e0
[15836:a057] An uncaught exception was raised
[15836:a057] -[NSManagedObject encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1001896e0
[15836:a057] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dc94716 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8bfe6470 objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dd2ad5a -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 186
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dc82c3e ___forwarding___ + 414
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8dc82a28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 232
5   Foundation                          0x00007fff86931401 _encodeObject + 1163
6   Foundation                          0x00007fff869323cc -[NSKeyedArchiver _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 410
7   Foundation                          0x00007fff869320c9 -[NSArray(NSArray) encodeWithCoder:] + 473
8   Foundation                          0x00007fff86931401 _encodeObject + 1163
9   Foundation                          0x00007fff869358f9 +[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:] + 182
10  iLoadPix                            0x0000000100003c21 -[HASArticleInitializer initialize:] + 3793
11  Foundation                          0x00007fff86926842 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
12  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff88553782 _pthread_start + 327
13  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff885401c1 thread_start + 13
```

Core Data Model:
[Entity 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDWUD.png)
[Entity 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plWpx.png)

As I said, everything works fine if I don't save the array, the NSLog is correct, too. If it matters I use NSThreads (but I don't think so because everything else works just fine) :-(

Please help me! Thanks so much in advance! :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transformable properties are archived via keyed archiving/unarchiving... however NSManagedObject isn't designed to be archived this way. (It doesn't implement the `NSCoding` protocol.)

To get around this you could turn your managed objects into dictionary representations, but the most natural thing seems to be to use a core data relationship between the 2 entities. Is there a reason you didn't model a relationship here?

Comment: Actually I do have relationships between them but I think I don't use them (I added the pictures of the model above.
I have two tableviews in my app and one displays the manufacturers and the other displays the belonging articles. So I bound the ArticleController's Content Array to the ManufacturerArrayController.

Comment: sorry--i don't read carefully. Why do you want to save the arrays?

Comment: Because I want to display them in the articlesTableView. Is there a way to do that without the arrays? Or without *saving* them?

Comment: Well (almost) the whole point of Core Data is persistence... anyway, the same information is stored in your relationship. For your table, just do a Core Data fetch (query) to get the objects in interest you want to display in your table. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Sorry, I fell asleep ;-) (it's been night here in Germany) ... Yes, that its *exactly* what I want and what I tried to but I didn't get it work. That's why I changed the manufacturer entity to hold the array of articles. Could you perhaps give me a hint how to do that? (Thank you for your patience!)